# Should a web service response include empty values?

Tags: web-services, rest, jaxb, unmarshalling

When invoking a web service I get a dynamic response in XML format.

So response could be :

```
<response>
<test1>test1</test1>
<test2>test1</test2>
<test3>test1</test3>
<test4>test1</test4>
</response>
```

or :

```
<response>
<test1>test1</test1>
<test2>test1</test2>
</response>
```

But I think the response should be static in order for the Java class to be unmarshalled correctly from the XML.

So instead of

```
<response>
<test1>test1</test1>
<test2>test1</test2>
</response>
```

This should be :

```
<response>
<test1>test1</test1>
<test2>test1</test2>
<test3></test3>
<test4></test4>
</response>
```

This means I can now handle the response and check for missing data.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB Marshalling with null fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858598/jaxb-marshalling-with-null-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Default Null Representation

By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will treat a property as an optional element.  As such null values are represented as the element being absent from the document.

### Alternate Representation of Null

Alternatively you have null represented by including the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute on it.  This is achieved by annotating your property with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)`.

```
<date xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

### Invalid Null Representation

An empty element is not a valid representation for null.  It will be treated as an empty String which will be invalid for all non-String types.

```
<date/>
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

---

### Update

> SO  test1 test1  is
>   a valid response but the fields test3 & test4 will be set to null ?

What happens is that nothing is done for the fields/properties that correspond to absent nodes.  They will keep there default values, which are by default initialized to `null`.

**Java Model (Root)**

In the model class below I have initialed the fields to have values that are not `null`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    String foo = "Hello";

    String bar = "World";

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The document being marshalled `<root/>` does not have any elements corresponding to the mapped fields/properties in the model class.

```java
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<root/>");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(root.foo);
        System.out.println(root.bar);
    }

}
```

**Output**

We see that the default values were output.  This shows that a set operation was not performed for the absent nodes.

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: SO <response>
<test1>test1</test1>
<test2>test1</test2>
</response> is a valid response but the fields test3 & test4 will be set to null ?

Comment: @user470184 - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [JAXB Marshalling with null fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858598/jaxb-marshalling-with-null-fields) 
and also [What's the purpose of minOccurs, nillable and restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111936/whats-the-purpose-of-minoccurs-nillable-and-restriction)

Use `@XmlElement(nillable = true)` for those null/blank value fields to display; but pay particular attention to your ***date*** fields.