# JAXBElementRef does not generate nillable="true"

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxbelement

for the request for my web service, I wanted to differ between requested `null` value and missing tag. In other words I needed the following element definition:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="minzeronil" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

I developed the web service code-first, so I defined the element using `JAXBElementRef`:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

  @XmlElementDecl(name = "minzeronil", namespace = XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE)
  public JAXBElement<String> createMinzeronil(final String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE, "minzeronil"), String.class, value);
  }

}
```

Now, I expected to see `nillable = "true"` in the definition of the element. Instead, I got:

```
<xs:element name="minzeronil" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element ref="tns:minzeronil" minOccurs="0"/>
```

How can I generate `nillable = "true"` from my java code? ... and still use JAXBElement in my code and its methods like `isNil()` ...

**UPDATE:** I deploy the code on glassfish, so glassfish is the one that generates the wsdl and xsd.

Comment: The following may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665550/jaxb-element-that-is-both-optional-and-nillable/19666240#19666240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `@XmlElement(nillable = true)` in your Java Class

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
public String getAString() {
    return AString;
}
```

Refer to this [Stack Overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737538/should-a-web-service-response-include-empty-values/18743766#18743766)

Comment: if only it were that straightforward ... when I use this notation, I will not be able to check if the attribute is true in my java code. That's why I used `@XmlElementRef`